# how to have ffmpeg delay 1 minute to system then run stream?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, stream, rtmp

i want to restream with ffmpeg , how do i make it delay 1 minute ( but save to ffmpeg ) then stream ?

the reason for the 1 minute delay is because my connection is slow, if it waits 1 minute it might help to keep it smooth

my command

```
ffmpeg -i "http://xxxxx/xxxx.m3u8" -c:v copy -c:a aac -async 1 -f flv rtmp://xxxxx/live
```

Comment: Try `stdbuf -i10M ffmpeg …` and see if it helps … You may iIncrease or decrease the number `10` (*in megabytes*) to adjust the standard input stream buffering.